# Finding Music folder after updating with OS X EI Capitan

Tags: macbook-pro, itunes, finder

We are having trouble locating iTunes music folder. Prior to updating with OS X EI Capitan, we could easily find the music folder in the Finder sidebar, but now we don't know how to get it back with all our music, media, etc.

Answer (score 2):

All the iTunes content is inside the directory: `~/Music/iTunes` more precisely: `/Users/<your_user_name>/Music/iTunes`.

You can use special application tool like [DaisyDisk](https://daisydiskapp.com) to locate some particular content inside your Mac computer.

Answer (score 1):

The Sidebar is just a handy place to find stuff. If an item has been removed from the Sidebar, it is easily put back by dragging its icon from its source location on the drive. In your case, open the /Users/*your_user_name* folder from the HD and drag the Music icon into the Sidebar.

This [Support Document](https://support.apple.com/kb/PH22175?locale=en_US&viewlocale=en_US) at Apple may help in greater detail.

Answer (score 1):

Music is a default folder under FAVORITES on the Sidebar of Finder and you should be able to select it and then see your iTunes Folder.  If the Sidebar isn't shown, click Finder > View > Show Sidebar. If Music isn't in Finder's Sidebar then go to the menu bar Finder > Preferences... > Sidebar and click the checkbox by Music to have it appear in the Sidebar.

If the iTunes folder isn't in the Music folder, then in Spotlight type iTunes and see if it shows as a folder under FOLDERS.

Or in a Terminal use the following command to locate folders named "iTunes":

```
mdfind 'kMDItemFSName == "iTunes"'
```

It will probably output more then one "iTunes" folder as there are also, e.g., `/Library/Documentation/Applications/iTunes`, `/Users/$USER/Music/iTunes`, `/Library/iTunes` etc., however one of the pathnames generated should contain your music.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like the sidebar preferences got reset when you upgraded to El Capitan. If that is all that is going on, it should be simple to fix. The sidebar is just a list of shortcuts to where the folders actually are, so we just need to put the shortcut back. First, make sure that Finder is the application that you are working in, either by clicking the Finder face in the dock or clicking anywhere on your desktop.

[image: Finder face]

Then, click on the word Finder at the top of your computer next to the  symbol, then click Preferences. In Preferences there is a button that says Sidebar. Click that, then make sure the box next to Music is checked.

Alternatively, you can click on the word Go in the menu bar, and then select Home in the menu that comes up.

[image: Menu options to click]

This will show you your Home folder, which contains your Music folder. From there you can simply drag the folder to the sidebar under Favorites and it will be back where your used to seeing it, or you can just open it to go inside the folder as usual.

Comment: If whoever voted this down (or anyone else) would let me know what I could do to improve this answer, I would really appreciate it. Thanks.